# Creating data structures in C

Tags: c

I am using some self written data structures in my C program (vector / heap / deque etc). Example of vector:

```
typedef struct Vector {
    void **vector;
    size_t size;
    size_t capacity;
} Vector;
```

Which way to create them is better? As a pointer to an object or as an object (like in c++)? 
Example:

```
Vector *vectorCreate(){
    Vector *vector = malloc(sizeof(Vector));
    ...
    return vector;
}
```

or

```
Vector vectorCreate(){
    Vector vector;
    ...
    return vector;
}
```

Comment: Depends on how you intend to use it. The former method is providing the memory management built-in and does not have the overhead of copying structures. The latter method leaves the memory management to the caller and has this overhead. If you want combine, you can have something like `vectorCreate(Vector*)` which will leave the memory management to the caller (to pass pre-allocated pointer) but will initialize it by itself.

Comment: Why is this a double pointer `void **vector;`

Comment: @EugeneSh. Okey, that makes sense, thank You!

Comment: @Nina That's a pointer to the array of void pointers.

Comment: I suggest looking for inspiration here: https://github.com/tylov/STC/blob/master/docs/cvec_api.md